# How to show uploaded files using initialFiles on material-ui-dropzone?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am using reactjs and trying to show my uploaded files in preview area of material-ui-dropzone.
First I fetch my uploaded files (just their name) from server and then set it into state. I set `initialFiles={uploadedFiles}` but my uploaded files not show in preview area. How can I fix that?

My code:

```
import { DropzoneArea } from "material-ui-dropzone";

export function UploadedFileDropzone(props) {
   const [uploadedFiles, setUploadedFiles] = useState([]);

   function getUploadedFiles() {
      // const files = fetch file names from server
      setUploadedFiles(files);
   }

   useEffect(() => {
      getUploadedFile();
   }, []);

   return (
      <div>
         <DropzoneArea initialFiles={uploadedFiles}/>
      </div>
   )
}
```

Here is what I had and what I expect
[image: what I had and what I expect]

Answer (score 0):

There is a property of "DropzoneArea" called 'useChipsForPreview' by default it's false set it to true you will get the desire output

Answer (score 0):

DropZoneArea accepts both string array and object file array. The string array should be an array of URLs that directly point to the image on your server. Here is an example:

const initialImageLinks = ["http://localhost:8001/files/image.png", http://localhost:8001/files/another_image.png]

```
<DropzoneArea
  filesLimit={filesLimit}
  onChange={onImageUpload}
  acceptedFiles={["image/*"]}
  initialFiles={initialImageLinks}
/>
```

So, in your case, make sure that the 'files' variable is properly set. It should be a list of URLs that directly allow you to open the image.